# What does "...yet has been trailed..." mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> No one has felt the pressure more than White House chief of staff Reince Priebus, who was christened as the man "in charge" by the President mere weeks ago **yet has been trailed ever since** by snipers regarding his aptitude and longevity for the job.

Does the **yet has been trailed** mean he's never been targeted? Or is it otherwise?

http://time.com/4672974/donald-trump-white-house-chaos/

Comment: You might be confused by the various meanings of the word *[yet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yet)*. In this sentence it is synonym of *however/in spite of that*. If this is the case there's already been a question on that matter on ELL: [How to use yet](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65800/how-to-use-yet).

Answer (score 1):

The word "yet" in this sentence acts as a coordinating conjunction.  Another way you might write it would be:

> No one has felt the pressure more than White House chief of staff Reince Priebus, who was christened as the man "in charge" by the President mere weeks ago**,** yet **he** has been trailed ever since by snipers regarding his aptitude and longevity for the job.

The word choice is a little flowery, but saying "he has been trailed ever since by snipers..." suggests that "snipers" have been (following/harassing) putting pressure on him because of their feelings about his aptitude and longevity.

Comment: +1, but I think I would describe the wording here as "a little incoherent" rather than "a little flowery". I can't decide whether the "regarding [...]" phrase is supposed to modify "snipers" or "trailed", but either way, it clashes with the metaphor.